# regex tokenizer period vs. ellipsis

Tags: python, nltk

I want to separate strings by sentence-ending punctuation marks (so ".", "?", "!") excluding ellipsis ("..."). Note that the ellipsis in the text I'm dealing with are three periods, not a dedicated Unicode string.

Currently what I do is

`tokenizer = nltk.RegexpTokenizer(r"[?.!]+", gaps=True)`

But this still splits the string at `...`. *However*, I want to keep splitting at `!!!` or `??` , just not for multiple consecutive instances of `.`. What's the easiest way to distinguish between the ellipsis and the period, if I want to use RegexpTokenizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work `[?!]+|(?<!\.)\.{1,2}(?!\.)`

We match either any non-zero amount of `?` and `!` or 1 or 2 dots that are not followed by the dot and not preceded by the dot.

But lookbehind and lookahead have bad performance.

BTW, I found this site https://pythex.org to check python regexes